# connect multiple reducers using decorator in redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, ecmascript-next

I have multiple reducers, how can I use connect? the user is just one of them.

```
@connect(state=>state.user, {getUser1})
class MyApp extends React.Component {

}
```

Comment: FYI, decorators are not part of the ECMAScript6 (2015) but the ECMA2016.

Comment: @lilezek: No, decorators are not part of any release yet.

Comment: @FelixKling Yes, you are right. I've read bad sources about the decorators proposal.

Answer (score 3):

Just include other parts of a state and return it in object

```
@connect(state=>({user: state.user, other: state.other}))
```